# How to create fluid layout in Flex3? With an Example.

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

How to create fluid layout in Flex3? With an Example.

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: What's not clear (and not at all covered in Tour de Flex or any other component explorer, Spark or otherwise) is how you mix pixel and percentage-based layouts. Imagine an application with a small "control panel" HGroup across the bottom. It's a fixed size - it will always be, say, 100pixels. Now, how do you set the remainder of the application area (the top part) to fill the remaining area? I _could_ just calculate the remaining #pixels and set the height of the top box to that number. But what then if I resize the app (either interactively, or even just at compile time?)

Answer (score 0):

Use container components that use relative layout ( e.g. HBox, VBox, etc. ) instead of absolute ( e.g. Canvas )

Have a look at the container samples in [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/#sampleId=3700;illustIndex=0;docIndex=0). Try the AIR App as well.